# Making code more readable, iterating over inner map

Tags: java

So currently I looking for some hints from more experienced programmers. I am in the point where, when looking into my code it seems not readable, what is probably big flaw. So lets go to the code itself:

In one the classes I have method:

```
    protected void createModelsCharacterisitcListGroup(Map<CharacterType, Map<String, String>> characters) {

        for (Entry<CharacterType, Map<String, String>> outterEntry : characters.entrySet()) {
            for (Entry<String, String> innerEntry : outterEntry.getValue().entrySet()) {
                outterEntry.getKey().create(characters.get(outterEntry.getKey()).get(innerEntry.getKey()), source.getStringified(innerEntry.getKey()));
            }
        }

}
```

And `CharacterType` is the enum like this:

```
public enum CharacteristicType {
    TYPE1 {

        @Override
        public void create(String name, String value){

        }
    },
    TYPE2{

        @Override
        public void create(String name, String value) {

        }
    };

    public abstract void create(String name, String value);
}
```

So what I want to do is:

Call method `create` for given `CharacterType` in `Map` with `Strings` from inner map

Comment: hello, for this type of questions please head over to [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: 1) Instead of using an explicit `for` with `.entrySet()` consider using `characters.forEach((key, value) -> { ... })`. 2) do you realize that `characters.get(outerEntry.getKey())` is just `outerEntry.getValue()`? 3) `outerEntry.getValue().get(innerEntry.getKey())` is just `innerEntry.getValue()`

Comment: I think [CodeReviwe](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would have given more feedback, but probably also would have mentioned CharacterType/CharacteristicType, TYPE1/TYPE2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case it seems like you can simplify your code.

First of all, I don't know why you get the entries but then re-fetch the values:

- `characters.get(outterEntry.getKey())` this is just `outterEntry.getValue()` with extra steps, because `characters` can only have one value associated to `outterEntry.getKey()` and your code does not modify the `characters` map.
- `outterEntry.getValue().get(innerEntry.getKey())` this is just `innerEntry.getValue()` with extra steps. You are iterating over `outterEntry.getValue()`.

If you use the `Map.forEach` method which allows you to unpack the entries you can reduce the code to:

```
characters.forEach((outerKey, outerValue) -> {
    outerValue.forEach((innerKey, innerValue) -> {
        outerKey.create(innerValue, source.getStringified(innerKey));
    });
});
```

I generally use `Entry`s only when I need to modify them (like change the value associated with a key in the map). Most of the time I find `Map.forEach` to be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

May be something like that:

```java
    protected void createModelsCharacterisitcListGroup(Map<CharacterType, Map<String, String>> characters) {
       characters.forEach(this::create);
    }

    private void create(CharacterType type, Map<String, String> args) {
        args.forEach((key, name) -> type.create(name, source.getStringified(key)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a map containing another map, I suggest you use classes to store the data instead. You could create an object storing the inner Map containing the data that's in the map. Preferably as fields. I would also suggest not adding methods to enums, generally the only thing placed in enums are static values.

To give you an exact example of what I mean I would need to have an explanation of what you'd want to achieve but if you have multiple character types with a different implementation. Why not create an abstract Character class or interface which defines the make method. Then you can give every type (assuming there won't be hundreds) it's own class. Maybe you won't even need a make method in that case since the values can be set properly in the constructor.

These are all just ideas, if you explain the exact purpose I could try to give you a better example of what I mean